# How to do animations of mouse events occur in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've some mouse events in some elements as [illustrated here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4x9g5uod/)

```
$("div").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("bigDiv", 1000);
});
```

The problem is: if two or more mouse events are fired, they don't wait the previous finish to fire, they fire immediately. How to do they wait their time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("div").on("mouseenter", function(){
        if(!$('div').is(':animated'))
            $(this).addClass("bigDiv", 1000);
    });

    $("div").on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("bigDiv", 1000);
    });
});
```

Is this what you wanted?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x9g5uod/2/)

Comment: If I pass the mouse through all the divs, it is firing all together, I want to block this.

Comment: Right, I thought you wanted the animation to be fired once per block and not multiple times. I'll check that.

Comment: Updated (changed `$(this)` to `$('div')` in the condition). Check the updated Fiddle.